# Ng hide/show dosn't work . In angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

Trying to hide/show a column

```html
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked"/> Hide
<div ng-hide="checked">
 hide Me
</div>
```

what is wrong here?

I've originally tried it on a table... 
Hiding/showing a specific column.
but lets keep it simple. 
It should have work on both the same, right?

```html
 <input type="checkbox" ng-model="hideCoupons"/> Hide Coupons

  <tr  *ngFor="let c of customers| customerFilter:custTerm ; let 
 i=index"> 
<td scope="row">{{c.id}}</td>
<td>{{c.custName}}</td>
<td>{{c.password}}</td>
<td ng-hide="hideCoupons" style="font-size:9px; color:red">{{c.coupons | 
json}}</td>
<td class="btn btn-danger" (click) ="removeCustomers(c.id)" 
(click)="removeCustomersUi(i)"><a id="delete">DELETE</a></td>  
</tr>
```

btw, I also tried $scope.IsVisible = true. but my ts file dosn't seem to recognize the $scope...

Comment: `ng-hide`, `ng-model` and `$scope` all come from AngularJs - You can't use these in Angular.

Comment: i am using angular4.
tried [(ngModel)] as well...
so..How do I hide and show a column?

Comment: What Angular is this question about?

Comment: In Angular 4, you can use `*ngIf="!checked"`.

Comment: ConnorsFan, thanx man! that worked!

Answer (score 2):

The problem was solved thanks to *ngIf="!checked".
Thank you very much everyone!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [NgIf directive](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf)

**Angular 5 demo:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ejrdwr?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="checked"/> Hide
<div *ngIf="!checked">
 hide Me
</div>
```